# Excel table find and copy cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy, find

I have a table series of tables with 3 columns which record the location of items. Eg table A, A1, A2.... B, B1 etc. etc.:

Each table contains the following columns:

1. Customer eg. 2. Description and 3. Spec. Number

I recently audited the physical shelves and created the same table alongside the old table in an excel spreadsheet. This new table only has data in the spec. Number column and contains less entries as some of the items on the shelf have been removed. The tables are not aligned on the same rows. i.e. not directly across from each other.

What I would like to do is create a formula to find for example spec number 12345 in the old table and copy the customer and description in the old table which is in the 2 cells to the left of the spec number into the two cells to the left of the new table I have for 12345?

This is fairly complicated but I would think is doable? This is a screen grab of what I am trying to do:

[image]

As you can see 4780 was in the shelf when I did the stock take and I only took down the spec. number to be quick. Now I want to copy the customer and print design details over from the 4780 in the table on the left automatically and do this then for the rest of the spreadsheet if possible.

Comment: I have added a screen grab of the situation. I am out of my dept with this stuff and struggling to get my head around it. Anyone have an idea of the formula I should be trying. I tried some Vlookup stuff but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: That's done it you absolute hero!! Thanks sooo much, I really appreciate it! Can I give you rep or something on this? Thanks M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH($J4,$D:$D,0))
```

met the requirements, copied one cell to the right and both formulae then copied down to suit. OP's image does not show sheet headings, but the positions assumed by the above formula are:

[image: SO24304463 example]

So the formula looks for the J4 value (`4780`) in ColumnD and if found the [MATCH function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) returns the row number concerned, that then is taken by the [INDEX function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_function.php) to determine the relevant cell in ColumnB from which to output the content.

The third parameter in MATCH is `0` to require exact matching only.

The `#N/A` results could be suppressed by wrapping the formula in [IFERROR](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/iferror-function-HA001231765.aspx).